# How to check internet connection applescript

Tags: applescript

noob here trying to teach myself applescript and generally not very smart so apologies :|

i was looking at this question and the answers

[Check for active internet connection with Applescript/Automator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224718/check-for-active-internet-connection-with-applescript-automator][1])

and i wanted to make a applescript that runs constantly in the background and that puts a red dot in the menubar when i don't have an internet connection and a green one when i don't (using the AnyBar application) but i can't get it to work properly.

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong. thank you so much!

`repeat
    repeat with i from 1 to 2
        try
            do shell script "ping -o -t 2 www.google.com"
            exit repeat
            tell application "AnyBar" to set image name to "green"
        on error
            tell application "AnyBar" to set image name to "orange"
            delay 2
            if i = 2 then tell application "AnyBar" to set image name to "red"
        end try
    end repeat

    delay 60
end repeat`

Comment: You will never get to the line that sets it green - you always exit the repeat before that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use an applet (script saved as application) with an `idle` handler rather than an infinite repeat loop

```
property imageName : "red"
property delayValue : 60
property googleURL : "http://www.google.com"

on run
    set imageName to "red"
end run

on idle
    if (count (get ((googleURL as URL)'s host & {dotted decimal form:""})'s dotted decimal form)) > 0 then
        set imageName to "green"
    else
        if imageName is "green" then
            set imageName to "orange"
            set delayValue to 2
        else if imageName is "orange" then
            set imageName to "red"
            set delayValue to 60
        end if
    end if
    tell application "AnyBar" to set image name to imageName
    return delayValue
end idle
```

Comment: thanks vadian. i did what you suggested but something is wrong with the code because the dot in my menubar is red and my internet is working fine. it was green for quite some time before that.

Comment: I edited the post to use an old but still operational way to check the internet connection. Save the script as application with option `stay open` and run the applet.

Comment: i have no idea what you're doing there with `code` (count (get ((googleURL as URL)'s host & {dotted decimal form:""})'s dotted decimal form)) > 0 then but it works like a dream! finally ... a use for the AnyBar app! thank you.